# How to change prometheus jmx exporter rules in spark-operator image working as extension of gcr.io/spark-operator/spark:v3.0.0-hadoop3

Tags: apache-spark, dockerfile, prometheus, jmx-exporter, spark-operator

We are trying to substitute the `prometheus.yaml` in `/etc/metrics/conf` as it hosts older rules. We try to copy new rules file:

```
RUN mkdir -p /etc/metrics/conf
COPY conf/prometheus.yaml /etc/metrics/conf/prometheus.yaml
```

But the rules are not picked up and prometheus still ignores the new metrics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sad truth is that in fact the folder and file is alredy there (looks like a symlink to `/etc/metrics/conf/..data/prometheus.yaml` location).

We had to work it around with

1. copying files to new location

   COPY conf/prometheus.yaml /etc/metrics/conf2/prometheus.yaml
2. add configFile parameter to the helm chart:

   configFile: "/etc/metrics/conf2/prometheus.yaml"

That causes javaagent's properties passed to jmx-exporter to use this new `prometheus.yaml` location